# Insert minutes and hour on d3.js timeseries plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, date-format, timeserieschart

I'm using this [snippet](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) to understand how d3.js works.

I changed this line of code -> `var parseDate = d3.time.format('%H-%M-%e-%b-%y').parse;`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format('%H-%M-%e-%b-%y').parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data/plottingData/first.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>
```

because the file is formatted in this way:

```
11-30-1-May-12  582.13
10-30-1-Apr-12  382.13
9-30-1-Mar-12   482.13
...
```

but I'm continuing to view only `day-month` into `x-Axis`.

what's wrong?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing the date in correct format, but on X-axis you did not provide the format, on which you want to show date. So just use "xAxis.tickFormat(parseDate)" in your code. Example is here:

```js
d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H-%M-%e-%b-%y'));
```

Comment: it print for each date the time `00-00`, why?